# How to cluster geolocation (lat long) data by radius and having minimum points threshold

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-computing, dbscan, haversine

I have dataset approx 30k lat longs. I want to clusters those into N number of clusters having radius 4 KM and minimum points in each cluster should be 20. I read many questions on stackoverflow but not getting the excact.
Though I tried with below codes

```
'df = pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx')
coords = df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].values

#Algorithm 

kms_per_radian = 6371.0088
epsilon = 4 / kms_per_radian
db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=20, metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(coords)) 
#metric='haversine' for lat long distance calculation
```

Same way I used OPTICS algorithm too,but in both algorithm I am not getting expected clusters.

Imp is points belonging to a cluster should not have more than 4KM distance from centroid (Imaginary)i.e. Points within 4KM radius from centroid should get clustered n should have minimum points 20.

So, which is the correct way to cluster this ?

Comment: We would need more info, what is DBSCAN?

Comment: Hi @BrunoVermeulen , DBSCAN and OPTICS are ML algorithms for clustering.